# Beagle Bone Black not retaining static IP

Tags: linux, debian, networking

I have a Beagle Bone Black to which I have assigned a static IP. My interfaces file is as follows.

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.16.41.226
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 172.16.41.1
```

The BBB has the IP that I assigned after boot up, but the IP is lost when I unplug the LAN cable and plug it back.

`ifconfig` command does not show any ip against `eth0` .

Comment: 266, really? are you sure?

Comment: I am sorry it is 226

Comment: does it makes a difference taking out the "allow-hotplug"? I do not have it in my ARM device.

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: After taking it out, you have to do "sudo service networking restart"

Comment: Tried doing that but no change.

Comment: Can it be because of some service, demon etc. ?

Comment: No idea. Any odd logs in `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/message` or `dmesg`?

Comment: I tried commenting auto eth0 and just kept 
allow-hotplug eth0

It seems to work now. But I cannot say for sure.

Comment: A grep on dmesg for eth0 gave this unusual thing

`[ 1081.736010] net eth0: phy found : id is : 0x7c0f1`
`[ 1081.741184] net eth0: phy 4a101000.mdio:01 not found on slave 1`
`[ 1081.751518] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready`
`[ 1083.741870] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready`